# Command pattern for simple text editor

Tags: java, object-oriented, design-patterns, text-editor

I was asked to code a TextPad with following functionality:

> `display()` – to display the entire content
>   `display(n, m)` – to display from line n to m
>   `insert(n, text)` – to insert text at line n
>   `delete(n)` – delete line n
>   `delete(n, m)` – delete from line n to m
>   `copy(n, m)` – copy contents from line n to m to clipboard
>   `paste(n)` – paste contents from clipboard to line n
>   `undo()` – undo last command
>   `redo()` – redo last command

They expected the textpad to be in memory (not as file). They also expected to handle error gracefully and the program to be menu driven.

Can someone please review the class structure implemented. Can it be improved so that code can be easily modified and extended?

```
public interface Command {

      void execute();

      void undo();

  }
```

---

```
package com.onedirect.oodesign.textpad;

public class PasteCommand implements Command {

  private TextPad textPad;

  private Integer line;

  public PasteCommand(TextPad textPad, Integer line){
    this.textPad = textPad;
    this.line = line;
  }

  @Override
  public void execute() {
    this.textPad.getLines().addAll(line, this.textPad.getClipBoard());
  }

  @Override
  public void undo() {
    for (int i = line; i < this.textPad.getClipBoard().size(); i++) {
      this.textPad.getLines().remove(i);
    }
  }


}
```

---

```
package com.onedirect.oodesign.textpad;

public class CopyCommand implements Command {

  private TextPad textPad;

  private Integer from;

  private Integer to;

  public CopyCommand(TextPad textPad, Integer from, Integer to) {
    this.textPad = textPad;
    this.from = from;
    this.to = to;
  }


  @Override
  public void execute() {
    this.textPad.setClipBoard(this.textPad.getLines().subList(from, to));
  }

  @Override
  public void undo() {

  }

}
```

---

```
package com.onedirect.oodesign.textpad;

import java.util.List;

public class DeleteCommand implements Command {


  private TextPad textPad;

  private Integer from;

  private Integer to;

  private List<String> lines;

  public DeleteCommand(TextPad textPad, Integer from, Integer to) {
    this.textPad = textPad;
    this.from = from;
    this.to =to;
  }

  @Override
  public void execute() {
    List<String> content = textPad.getLines();
    this.lines  = content.subList(from, to);
    for (int i = from; i < to && i<content.size(); i++) {
      content.remove(i);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void undo() {
    List<String> content = textPad.getLines();
    content.addAll(from, this.lines);
  }
}
```

---

```
package com.onedirect.oodesign.textpad;

import java.util.List;

public class DisplayCommand  implements Command {


  private TextPad textPad;

  private int m;

  private int n;

  public DisplayCommand(TextPad textPad, int m, int n) {
    this.textPad = textPad;
    this.m = m;
    this.n = n;
  }
  public DisplayCommand(TextPad textPad) {
    this.textPad = textPad;
    this.m = 0;
    this.n = this.textPad.getLines().size();
  }

  @Override
  public void execute() {
    List<String> list = this.textPad.getLines();
    list.subList(m, n).forEach(System.out::println);
  }

  @Override
  public void undo() {

  }


}
```

---

```
package com.onedirect.oodesign.textpad;

public class InsertCommand implements Command{

  private TextPad textPad;

  private Integer line;

  private String text;

  public InsertCommand(TextPad textPad, Integer line, String text) {
    this.line = line;
    this.textPad = textPad;
    this.text = text;
  }

  @Override
  public void execute() {
    this.textPad.getLines().add(line, text);
  }

  @Override
  public void undo() {
    this.textPad.getLines().remove((int)line);
  }
}
```

---

```
package com.onedirect.oodesign.textpad;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Stack;

public class TextPad {

  private List<String> lines;

  private Stack<Command> undo;

  private Stack<Command> redo;

  private List<String> clipBoard;

  public TextPad() {
    this.lines = new ArrayList<>();
    this.undo = new Stack<>();
    this.redo = new Stack<>();
    this.clipBoard = new ArrayList<>();
  }



  public List<String> getClipBoard() {
    return this.clipBoard;
  }

  public void setClipBoard(List<String> clipBoard) {
    this.clipBoard = clipBoard;
  }

  public List<String> getLines() {
    return lines;
  }

  public void display() {
    DisplayCommand displayCommand = new DisplayCommand(this);
    displayCommand.execute();
  }

  public void display(int m, int n) {
    DisplayCommand displayCommand = new DisplayCommand(this, m, n);
    displayCommand.execute();
  }

  public void insert(int n, String text) {
    clearRedo();
    InsertCommand insertCommand = new InsertCommand(this, n, text);
    insertCommand.execute();
    undo.push(insertCommand);
  }

  public void delete(int n) {
    delete(n, n);
  }

  public void delete(int n, int m) {
    clearRedo();
    DeleteCommand deleteCommand = new DeleteCommand(this, n, m);
    deleteCommand.execute();
    undo.push(deleteCommand);
  }

  public void copy(int n, int m) {
    clearRedo();
    CopyCommand copyCommand = new CopyCommand(this, n, m);
    copyCommand.execute();
  }

  public void paste(int n) {
    clearRedo();
    PasteCommand pasteCommand = new PasteCommand(this, n);
    pasteCommand.execute();
    undo.push(pasteCommand);
  }

  public void undo(){
    if(!undo.isEmpty()) {
      Command command = undo.pop();
      command.undo();
      redo.push(command);
    }
  }

  public void redo(){
    if(!redo.isEmpty()) {
      Command command = redo.pop();
      command.execute();
      undo.push(command);
    }
  }

  private void clearRedo() {
    while (!redo.isEmpty()) {
      redo.pop();
    }
  }

}
```

---

```
package com.onedirect.oodesign.textpad;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class TextPadDriver {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    TextPad textPad  = new TextPad();

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (true) {



      System.out.println("Please enter I to insert,"
          + " D to delete, C to copy , P to paste, "
          + "U to undo, R to redo, S to show, another to end");
      String c = in.next();

      switch (c) {

        case "I" :
          System.out.println("Give Line Number");
          Integer n = in.nextInt();
          System.out.println("Give Text");
          String text = in.next();
          textPad.insert(n, text);
          break;

        case "D":
          System.out.println("Give Line Number");
          Integer from = in.nextInt();
          System.out.println("Give Line Number");
          Integer to = in.nextInt();
          textPad.delete(from, to);
          break;

        case "C":
          System.out.println("Give Line Number");
          Integer fromCopy = in.nextInt();
          System.out.println("Give Line Number");
          Integer toCopy = in.nextInt();
          textPad.copy(fromCopy, toCopy);
          break;

        case "P":
          System.out.println("Give Line Number");
          Integer line = in.nextInt();
          textPad.paste(line);
          break;

        case "U":
          textPad.undo();
          break;

        case "R":
          textPad.redo();
          break;

        case "S":
          textPad.display();
          break;

         default:
           return;
      }


    }

  }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Since this has popped up in the close vote queue, does this code currently work as expected?

Comment: @Manu, is it possible for you to provide us the `TextPadDriver`?

Comment: @Roman I have added textPadDriver. But it doesn't cover all use cases.

Comment: @Graipher It is working and might not cover all edge cases. But I am more concerened about the structure than correctness of the code.

Comment: @Manu, thank you. I will edit my answer soon based on the `TextPadDriver`

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*. Question threads get incredibly messy if multiple answers review different versions of the same question.

Comment: @Mast The `TextPadDriver` was not an update, but a completion of the code, because this class is included in the UML, but is not specified here. Could you please add it again..

Comment: @Roman Since the only answer so far is yours, yes,  in this particular instance I will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Command Pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/command)

> [The] Command [Pattern] decouples the object that invokes the operation from the one that knows how to perform it.

In our case this means, that a `Command` invokes a method of `TextPad`. Though it is the way around and `TextPad` invokes a `Command`.

For example, when we look into the method `display` in `TextPad`:

> ```java
> public void display() {
>    DisplayCommand displayCommand = new DisplayCommand(this);
>    displayCommand.execute();
> }
> ```

Actually the logic should not be in a `Command` instead it needs to be in the `TextPad` itself. In the following I extract the logic out of the `DisplayCommand` into `TextPad`

```java
public void display() {
    List<String> list = this.textPad.getLines();
    list.subList(m, n).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

After that we can invoke the method in `DisplayCommand`.

```java
@Override
public void execute() {
    textPad.display();
}
```

---

The `TextPad` should work totally independent of `Command`. Additionally the fields `Stack<Command> undo` and `Stack<Command> redo` do not belong into `TextPad` but inside `TextPadDriver`.

---

### Why this Way?

Currently the code base violates against some opp-principles.

#### [Feature Envy](https://refactoring.guru/smells/feature-envy)

> A method accesses the data of another object more than its own data.

All implementations of `Command` operates on `TextPad`. For that the `TextPad` needs to offer its fields like `lines` and `clipBoard`. But actual the a `Command` should [Tell, Don't Ask](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html) a `TextPad`.

So the preferred way is

```java
@Override
public void execute() {
    textPad.display();
}
```

### [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)

> Only talk to your immediate friends.

This "problem" coheres with the Feature Envy, because every `Command` gets an instance of `TextPad` but only needs a sub information of it like `lines` or `clipBoard`.

> ```java
> this.textPad.getLines().remove(i)
> ```

The Law of Demeter do not allow the above statements, because you talk via `remove` to a "frind" (`lines`) of your "frind" (`textPad`), but you are only allow to talk to your "immediat friend" (`textPad`).

A valid statement under the Law of Demeter is

```java
this.textPad.removeLine(i)
```

---

## Empty Methods

> ```java
> @Override
> public void undo() {
>
> }
> ```

To have a empty method is totally valid, but it is better to leave it with a comment

```java
@Override
public void undo() {
    // nothing to do here
}
```

The benefits are that as a reader, I know that you are aware that you are not implementing it, and that you will know in the future that you have not forgotten the implementation.

---

## Constructor Chaining

> ```java
> public DisplayCommand(TextPad textPad, int m, int n) {
>    this.textPad = textPad;
>    this.m = m;
>    this.n = n;
> }
>
> public DisplayCommand(TextPad textPad) {
>    this.textPad = textPad;
>    this.m = 0;
>    this.n = this.textPad.getLines().size();
> }
> ```

It exists a constructor for all arguments `DisplayCommand(TextPad textPad, int m, int n)` and a constructor, which takes only one argument DisplayCommand(TextPad textPad) and sets `m` and `n` to some default values.

It is possible to chain the one-argument constructor to the full-args constructor.

```java
public DisplayCommand(TextPad textPad, int m, int n) {
    this.textPad = textPad;
    this.m = m;
    this.n = n;
}

public DisplayCommand(TextPad textPad) {
    this(textPad, 0, textPad.getLines().size());
}
```

Comment: I have added TextPad Driver Class. 

public void display() {
   DisplayCommand displayCommand = new DisplayCommand(this);
   displayCommand.execute();
}


public void display() {
    List<String> list = this.textPad.getLines();
    list.subList(m, n).forEach(System.out::println);
}



To which classes the above two methods should belong to?